# Opinion-based questions

Tags: discussion

We often close questions for being opinion based.  But apparently [Why is the Vasa Museum in Stockholm so Popular?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/143232/why-is-the-vasa-museum-in-stockholm-so-popular) is too interesting to get that treatment.  Inconsistent?

Comment: not if there's a clear non-opionated reason for it. See chx's answer there, arguably better than the accepted one.

Answer (score 4):

The question is not opinion based because it doesn't ask for opinions or recommendations, but for reasons for why the Vasa Museum is rated so high.

And it got an objective answer explaining what exactly is so unique in that museum. An intact ship 500 years old is quite unique and it's an objective fact, not an opinion.